# Manipulate Plot with Find Root Parameter

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, manipulate

I would like to plot the function G(r; x') as a function of r, but with parameter x'.

x' is the solution to F(x';p) = 0 where p is a parameter I can control.

Unfortunately F is messy and I must use FindRoot to solve F.

I would like to be able to use Manipulate to change p on a slider and see how that changes the plot of G.

For example,

F(x;p) = Log(p + px)

G(r;k) = k * Sin(log(k*r))

I'd like to plot G(r) with a slider for p.

How is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

F[x_, p_] := Log[p + p*x]
```

Exact solution

```
xp = SolveValues[F[x, p] == 0, x][[1]]

(* (1 - p)/p *)
```

Numeric solution

```
xp2[p_?NumericQ] := x /. FindRoot[F[x, p] == 0, {x, 2}]

G[r_, k_] := k*Sin[Log[k*r]]

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {G[r, xp /. p -> pv], G[r, xp2[pv]]},
  {r, 0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {r, G})],
 {{pv, 0.5, "p"}, 0.01, 0.99, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {pv}]
```

[image]